# Combine data from dynamic table in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I have multiple tables more than 500 (maybe even more, we are creating them dynamically) with the same schema.

Tables are named `CreateOrderRequestPending_TD001_%`.

Is there any fast way to fetch data from all those tables?

I am trying to do this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @TblName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @I INT = 0;

DECLARE Tbl_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'z_scope' 
      AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'CreateOrderRequestPending_TD001_%'

OPEN Tbl_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl_Cursor INTO @TblName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
    IF @I > 0 
       SET @SQL += ' UNION ALL ';

    SET @SQL += ' SELECT * FROM  ' + @TblName + ' '

    -- This query is more complex (having join with master table)
    SET @I = @I + 1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl_Cursor INTO @TblName
 END

 CLOSE Tbl_Cursor;
 DEALLOCATE Tbl_Cursor;  

 EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: In a technical sense, your dynamic SQL would likely need to have a UNION ALL between each table's SELECT statement - then you would get the results of all of the tables in one dataset.  However, I can't helping thinking that you should probably be reconsidering the solution that you've implemented, that requires the creation of 100s of dynamic table name (especially if the schema of them all is the same).  Can you not achieve your desired results with a single table, and a relevant KEY field that identifies the data (in the same way that your multiple tables is presumably doing)?

Comment: We were using single table till now We were facing the locking issue when Dealer upload order. We have more than 2k dealer and upload data 3k to 4k daily basis. Now we create table dealer wise.

Answer (score 0):

Issue

```
DROP VIEW COMBINED
;
CREATE VIEW COMBINED AS
    SELECT * FROM ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ...
```

where you dynamically produce the list of constituent tables.

Then query the view.

---

From time to time the set of constituent tables will change.

Fortunately it is extremely fast to DROP / re- CREATE a VIEW.

---

Consider using `dealer` as a partition key,
so you have a single relation maintained by the backend (no VIEWs).
Then transactions for a given dealer would
all contend for locks on one of the underlying DB objects.

Comment: what do i do when the new table is created. alter view again??

Comment: @Nazimtyagi - yes, with this solution you'd still need dynamic SQL to recreate the view whenever there are new base tables added (that need to be included in the view)